# gstreamer opencv receiving and editing a stream

Tags: c, opencv, gstreamer

My current project:

Send video from a device with a usb camera to a server, on the server do video processing and then send it to another client where it is displayed.

I have gotten gstreamer to work in the terminal:

On the receiving server:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! \
application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264 ! \
rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! \
timeoverlay shaded-background=true text="host" deltay=20 ! \
ximagesink async=true sync=false
```

On the capturing client:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src ! \
timeoverlay shaded-background=true text="pi" ! \
video/x-raw,height=480,width=640,framerate=30/1 ! \
videoconvert ! omxh264enc ! rtph264pay ! \
udpsink host=136.225.61.68 port=5000
```

This works very well and the video is being transfered. Now I need to (on the receiving end) capture the stream in c code so that I can do face detect ect with opencv and send this stream to another client. Either this is done with the gstreamer bad plugins that have opencv support or it is done by converting the stream into mats and using opencv. Does anybody know which is easier and do you have any examples? (I am using gstreamer 1.0).

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to the first step. I can now use gst_parse_launch to receive the stream in C code.

The code on the server side is now as follows:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  GstElement *pipeline;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Build the pipeline */
  pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("udpsrc port=5000 ! \
  application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264 ! \
  rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! \
  timeoverlay shaded-background=true deltay=20 ! \
  ximagesink async=true sync=false", NULL);

  /* Start playing */
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  /* Wait until error or EOS */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
  msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

  /* Free resources */
  if (msg != NULL)
    gst_message_unref (msg);
  gst_object_unref (bus);
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  return 0;
}
```

Now the next step is to connect this with OpenCV or to an OpenCV plugin so that I can do facedetect etc.

Comment: [Please use Answers exclusively to answer the question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/92107). If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. (I've edited your post to be just an answer - you can retrieve the new question portion from the edit history.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use opencv VideoCapture function to receive the stream and then you can have image processing on it.